# WiFi Tether Causes a BSOD in Laptop Using Intel WiFi Hardware

Tags: wi-fi, nexus-4, crashes, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering

On a rooted Nexus 4 using stock 4.2.2, if I enable Wifi tether then connect my laptop (a Lenovo T520 using Centrino Advanced-N 6205 hardware with driver v15.3.1.2) I get a BSOD within seconds. I am using the stock tether app.

I read elsewhere that I am not the only one with this problem, but Intel refuses to acknowledge it. I even waited for an updated Wifi driver to come out, which I installed today, but the problem persists. According a thread on XDA-Dev, the [workaround](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=26089470&postcount=6) is to set the Local IP to 192.168.1.100 instead of 192.168.1.1 and the DHCP starting IP to 192.168.1.101 instead of 192.168.1.10. But since I am using the stock tethering app these settings are not available. **Is there a tweak app that would allow me to do this? Or are there other workarounds to this issue?**

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a documented bug related to tethering between INTEL wireless and QUALCOMM S4 based mobile phones, leading to disconnection or BSOD. It has been documented [here](https://communities.intel.com/thread/33377) and discussed [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2229453).

Answer (score 0):

Its happening to me as well since yesterday. Never happens with dell but first time in HP. Read somewhere that enabling FIPS in wifi setting in laptop will solve this problem will check and revert.